# Using \notblank in etoolbox's \ifboolexpr statment

Tags: macros, etoolbox

As the title says, I am currently trying to use etoolbox's `\ifboolexpr` statment on `\notblank` conditions but I am having issues with it. 
The code concerned looks like this :

```
\ifboolexpr{%
  test {\notblank{\Temp@Temp@Text@a}} or %
  test {\notblank{\Temp@Temp@Text@b}} or %
  test {\notblank{\Temp@Temp@Text@c}}    %
}%
{}{}%
```

It however generates a bunch of errors. 
Even trying something like this does not quite seem to work any better :

```
\ifboolexpr{%
  test {\notblank{}} or %
  test {\notblank{}} or %
  test {\notblank{}}    %
}%
{}{}%
```

The maximum I am able to use without issues is (given as a MWE. To reproduce my issues, just substitute the `\ifbookexpr` statment) :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside,onecolumn]{report}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\def\Temp@Temp@Text@a{testa}
\def\Temp@Temp@Text@b{testb}
\def\Temp@Temp@Text@c{testc}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\ifboolexpr{%
  test {} or %
  test {} or %
  test {}    %
}%
{true}{false}%

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

So my question is :

- What am I doing wrong ?
- How to solve it ?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example!

Comment: I edited it to give an MWE. The issues can be reproduced just by replacing the right bit of code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The documentation of `etoolbox` states that the argument to `\ifblank` and to `\notblank` is *not* expanded. Therefore `\notblank{\xyz}` will return "true" no matter what's the definition of `\xyz`.

If you want complete expansion you have to ask for it explicitly, for example

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage,twoside,onecolumn]{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}

\makeatletter

\def\Temp@Temp@Text@a{testa}
\def\Temp@Temp@Text@b{testb}
\def\Temp@Temp@Text@c{testc}

\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\ifboolexpr{%
    test {\noexpand\notblank{\Temp@Temp@Text@a}} or 
    test {\noexpand\notblank{\Temp@Temp@Text@b}} or 
    test {\noexpand\notblank{\Temp@Temp@Text@c}}    
  }}\x{\typeout{true}}{\typeout{false}}%

\def\Temp@Temp@Text@a{}
\def\Temp@Temp@Text@b{}
\def\Temp@Temp@Text@c{}

\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
  \noexpand\ifboolexpr{%
    test {\noexpand\notblank{\Temp@Temp@Text@a}} or 
    test {\noexpand\notblank{\Temp@Temp@Text@b}} or 
    test {\noexpand\notblank{\Temp@Temp@Text@c}}    
  }}\x{\typeout{true}}{\typeout{false}}%

\makeatother

\end{document}
```

The first instance returns `true`, while the second one returns `false`.

Comment: As I pointed out in my second exemple, my main problem here is that the code does not compile even without anything in the `\notblank`. Therefore, the expansion problem is in fact secondary for now.

Comment: Well, nevermind, the real problem in my code was that I was apparently trying to use all of this an a piece of code that appears in an expend-only context, so using a robust way of expanding the storage macros first and using `\ifboolexpe` solved it. 

Therefore, your answer is good enough for me.

Answer (score 4):

The `catoptions` package has exactly what you need without further code. `\xifblankFT` means *fully expanded not blank*. There is also `\oifblankFT`, meaning *one-step expanded not blank*.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{catoptions}
\def\vgap{\par\bigskip}

\begin{document}
\def\tempa{testa}
\def\tempb{testb}
\def\tempc{testc}

First test (true):
\ifexprTF{%
  test {\xifblankFT{\tempa}} or
  test {\xifblankFT{\tempb}} or
  test {\xifblankFT{\tempc}}
}{
  true
}{
  false
}

\vgap
\def\tempa{}
\def\tempb{}
\def\tempc{}

Second test (false):
\ifexprTF{%
  test {\xifblankFT{\tempa}} or
  test {\xifblankFT{\tempb}} or
  test {\xifblankFT{\tempc}}
}{
  true
}{
  false
}

\def\tempd{x}

\vgap
Third test (false):
\ifexprTF{%
  ( test {\xifblankTF{\tempa}} or test {\xifblankTF{\tempb}} )
  and
  ( test {\xifblankFT{\tempc}} and test {\xifblankFT{\tempd}} )
}{
  true
}{
  false
}

\vgap
\def\tempe{00}
\newif\iftestbool

Fourth test (true):
\ifexprTF{%
  ( switch {tempe} or bool {testbool} )
  and
  (  ( test {\xifblankTF{\tempc}} and not test {\xifblankTF{\tempd}} )
     or
     ( test {\xifstrcmpTF\tempa\tempb} or not test {\ifxTF\tempc\tempd} )
  )
}{
  true
}{
  false
}
\end{document}
```

This type of boolean calculus is expensive. You only need to look at the tracelog to confirm this assertion. 99 percent of the time you can do with a much simpler test. For example, since `\xifstrcmpFT` is expandable, we have an economical test:

```
\def\do#1{\ifx\do#1\relax\else+\xifstrcmpFT{#1}{}01\expandafter\do\fi}
\ifnum0=\numexpr0\do\tempa\tempb\tempc\tempd\do
  true
\else
  false
\fi
```

Comment: This seems very nice but I cannot find documentation in the catoptions package about this kind of mechanics. Are you sure it is provided by this package and not another one that this one would load ?

Comment: It is surely provided by *catoptions* package, not by any dependency. Unfortunately, official work hasn't allowed me to fully document *catoptions* package. You can email your needs to me and I will reply with a solution, if available.

Comment: ok, I will probably need to look further into it, along with the solution provided by `etextools` and try to really understand what's going on with the different packages I found allowing me to do this to try to determine if I really prefer one of these solutions. 

For now, I will stick with the solution of having `\ifblank` used only by the frontend and then to use only expandable `\ifdefvoid` statments in the internal mechanics.